# PHP character encoding � sign instead of à

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, joomla1.5

Hi this is a very strange error I have on some pages of this joomla website:

http://www.pcsnet.it/news

If you go into the details of a specific news the à character is correctly displayed.

Other accented characters seem not affected.

I've checked that UTF-8 encoding is default both in the MySql db and that the text files are in UTF-8 encoding.

Other ideas?

Comment: what is your DB character set ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't double encode into UTF8? So you have your files in UTF8 and then on output you encode it in UTF8.

Comment: Don't forget the mysql<->database connection. That has to be set to utf-8 as well. The entire chain has to be utf-8, or you're going to get corrupted characters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is very interesting in your case is that it only affects the letter `à`! So it cannot be an encoding problem.

Here is my take on your problem. The letter `à` is encoded in two bytes in utf8. The first byte is `xC3`, which is `Ã` in latin-1, the second byte is... non breaking space! (The other accented letters, such as `è` are encoded by `Ã` followed by an other accented letter in latin-1, and they are not affected).

Therefore, my guess is that you have a script, somewhere, that removes, or replaces, the non-breaking space in latin-1, i.e., character `xA0`. The resulting lonely byte `xC3` cannot be displayed properly, so the general placeholder `�` is displayed instead. (just load your page in latin-1, you will see that I am right).

Find that script that removes non-breaking spaces, and you'll be fine.

Comment: That's a good catch as it displays only in stripped off text used for news preview. Do you think it could be some special character strip off regexp?

Comment: Yes, anything that operates on strings and is not unicode aware... look out for something with non-breaking spaces! :-)

Comment: So I ended up looking for /\xC3\s/ characters and replacing them with '\xC3\xA0 '

Comment: You just saved my day... Doing a preg_replace on a string was causing problem with the "à" character

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using `htmlentities`, `htmlspecialchars` or `html_entity_decode` on the text you retrieved from the database ? If so, you need to force UTF8 in the third parameter because it's not the default charset of these functions.

Example: `htmlentities('£hello', null, 'utf-8');`

Answer (score 0):

A � sign is usually an indication that the character the browser is trying to display is not available in the font used. It's probably not an à, if that works on other pages (using the same font).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true it is indeed an à character in UTF-8 format ... but after @Olivier answer I must say that you are right, it's a one byte à!